# Most Appropriate ASP.NET Control for Display Dynamic Query Result

Tags: asp.net, controls

I have a question about how to display dynamic query result in ASP.NET.
Let's say that I've gathered a query result from database and then display it on my page.
The problem is the ammount of columns in my query result is dynamic.
The first query may returns 3 columns but the next maybe 5 columns and so on.
I usually use `ASP:Repeater` for some case, but I don't think so for this case, since I need to declare the column explicitly (eg: in `ASP:Literal`, `ASP:Label`, etc).

NB: I need pagination too. Because the query result maybe return a hundred rows.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like ASP.NET Dynamic Data is the tool for you, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee845452.aspx

> inferring at run time the appearance and behavior of data entities from the database schema and deriving UI behavior from it

My only reservation: I've only used this once for actual work. On that occasion I needed to make some substantial changes after deployment - and it was a hassle, to the point I wished I'd just built my own (or even dumped everything into a `StringBuilder`.) Still though, if all you're doing is displaying tabular data, this is what you need.